# Fastest way to alter image by pixels in Android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, pixel

I am working on a feature of an app that allows the user to drag a color selector over an image and then replaces the pixels in a corresponding design. I have it working on Android emulator but is is slow on the actual device. When you drag the selector the color updating takes a long time which makes the selector jump around the screen instead of a smooth drag with gradual color changes.

```
balls.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(balls.getLayoutParams());
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    numtimes=numtimes+1;
                    int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
                    int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();
                    ImageView ColorImage = (ImageView) findViewById(300);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ColorImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(XIT,YIT);
                    UpdateColor(pixel);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



protected void UpdateColorOne(int pixel) {



    // Update Custom Ball
    ImageView balls = (ImageView) findViewById(27);
    GradientDrawable shapeNX = new GradientDrawable();
    shapeNX.setColor(pixel);
    balls.setBackground(shapeNX);

    //Update Image
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable = true;
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pimage, options);
    int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth()];

    myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());

    /BeginEdit
    for (int i = 0; i < myBitmap.getWidth() * myBitmap.getHeight(); i++) {
        int p = pixels[i];
        int R = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
        int G = (p >> 8) & 0xff;
        int B = p & 0xff;
        if (R > 200 && G < 200) {
            pixels[i] = pixel;
        }
    }


    myBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
    Drawable DD = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
    ImageView imgArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(1000);
    imgArrow.setImageDrawable(DD);
}
```

A couple of notes: 
- The speed is fine when just the custom ball/selector is being updated.
- I do not thing the size of the preset image is a major factor. I have tried commenting out the for loop (marked below as "Begin Edit") and it is still slow. The getPixels/setPixels and other bitmap stuff appears to be the slow point.

I have not found another way to achieve this effect! It needs to be done with the pixel data because the change is complex. I have this working fine on an iPhone - surely there must be a way to do it as efficiently on Android?

Comment: this is because you create a new `Bitmap` each time `UpdateColor` is called

Comment: `ImageView ColorImage = (ImageView) findViewById(300);` don't do this in onTouch. Also don't use magic numbers. Also don't do this in UpdateColor `ImageView balls = (ImageView) findViewById(27);` Also don't do this `Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pimage, options);`. In other words - a lot of things are wrong. You shouldn't do `findViewById() `each time you draw the pixel, since you need to do it only once in the beginning. It is slowing down things a lot. Don't decode resources each time. etc, etc.